# Writing a Django backend program that runs indefinitely -- what to keep in mind?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-authentication

I am trying to write a Django app that queries a remote database for some data, performs some calculations on a portion of this data and stores the results (in the local database using Django models). It also filters another portion and stores the result separately. My front end then queries my Django database for these processed data and displays them to the user.

My questions are:

1. How do I write an agent program that continuously runs in the backend, downloads data from the remote database, does calculations/ filtering and stores the result in the local Django database ? Particularly, what are the most important things to keep in mind when writing a program that runs indefinitely?
   Is using cron for this purpose a good idea ?
2. The data retrieved from the remote database belong to multiple users and each user's data must be kept/ stored separately in my local database as well. How do I achieve that? using row-level/ class-instance level permissions maybe?  Remember that the backend agent does the storage, update and delete. Front end only reads data (through http requests).
3. And finally, I allow creation of new users. If a new user has valid credentials for the remote database the user should be allowed to use my app. In which case, my backend will download this particular user's data from the remote database, performs calculations/ filtering and presents the results to the user. How can I handle the dynamic creation of objects/ database tables for the new users? and how can I differentiate between users' data when retrieving them ?

Would very much appreciate answers from experienced programmers with knowledge of Django. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

1) The standard get-go solution for timed and background task is Celery which has Django integration. There are others, like Huey https://github.com/coleifer/huey

2) The usual solution is that each row contains user_id column for which this data belongs to. This maps to User model using Django ORM's ForeignKey field. Do your users to need to query the database directly or do they have direct database accounts? If not then this solution should be enough. It sounds like it your front end has 1 database connection and all permission logic is handled by the front end, not the database itself.

3) See 2

Comment: Thank you Mikko. Users send http requests and views handle the requests so no direct database access.

Comment: Having separate user_id column (user field) for each row who owns it should be enough. Then just use this as a filter condition `Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)`